Popup page in Flutter instead of navigation
I am trying to create a functionality to open a page as a popup instead of navigating to it. Something similar to the screenshot below. I can't seem to find it anywhere in the documentation on how to achieve this. I have tried Navigator.push(), but it doesn't have options to achieve what I'm looking for

Any ideas?

You can use showModalBottomSheet.
Here's the documentation.

Thanks that worked. Additionally, I had to set isScrollControlled: true and wrap it with FractionallySizedBox to get the height that I wanted.

You can use this BottomSheet or Dialog to get popup the second page.
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
            return SecondPage();
          });
    });

or
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return SecondPage();
      });
});

